# How to create db migrations for local tortoise project?

Tags: python, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I have a FastAPI + tortose projects and I want to run the project locally with database `postgres://lom:lom@localhost:5432/lom` (database is created)

My code

```
# lom/app.py
class App:
    storage: S3Storage

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Config(_env_file=".env", _env_file_encoding="utf-8")
        self.__setup_sentry()
        ...
    def create_app(self, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> FastAPI:
        app = FastAPI()
        register_tortoise(
            app,
            modules={
                "models": [
                    "lom.core",
                    "aerich.models",
                ]
            }
```

I want to apply current migrations and create new migrations
I am trying

```
aerich init -t <Don't understand path>
```

What aerich command should I run and which parameters should I use?

```
├── lom
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── city.py
│   │   ├── company.py
├── 
├── migrations
│   ├── 001_main.sql
│   ├── 002_cities.sql
│   ├── 003_cities_declination.sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Initialize aerich by running the following command in the root directory of your project:
  `aerich init -t tortoise.Tortoise -p lom.models`

This will create an aerich.ini configuration file and a migrations directory in the root directory of your project.

- Configure the aerich.ini file to match your database connection settings. The default settings are for a SQLite database, so you will need to modify the [tortoise] section to use PostgreSQL instead.

`[tortoise]`

`# database_url = sqlite://db.sqlite3`

`database = lom`

`host = localhost`

`port = 5432`

`user = lom`

`password = lom`

`modules = ['lom.models']`

- Run the following command to create a new migration:
  `aerich migrate`

This will create a new migration file in the migrations directory.

- Run the following command to apply the migrations:
  `aerich upgrade`

This will apply all pending migrations to your database and the problem you're facing will be solved. Let me know if this helps